# Sample datasets with known outliers for IQR, Q-test and Z-test math tests

Tags: data-request

Is anyone aware of a source for sample data sets with known [outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier)? I've been looking around for years but haven't come up with a solution, short of creating my own limited database.

Sets with known outliers according IQR, Q-test and Z-test would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to look at the documentation for the relevant statistical procedures in popular statistics software, specifically in R or SAS.  Statistical function documentation usually has sample datasets and examples of the usages.
http://www.rdocumentation.org/
http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Wine Data Quality from the UCI Machine Learning Repository

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality

> These datasets can be viewed as classification or regression tasks. The classes are ordered and not balanced (e.g. there are munch more normal wines than excellent or poor ones). **Outlier detection algorithms could be used to detect the few excellent or poor wines.** Also, we are not sure if all input variables are relevant. So it could be interesting to test feature selection methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Dixon's Q.
2. I'm having trouble understanding why you don't just make up a data set to specifications, if the goal is validation of outlier detection? A simple mixture distribution will suffice, but a data set can be constructed to have the same data issues that the expected empirical data will have.

Comment: Maybe point 1 would be less off-topic if you explained why?

Comment: Dixon's Q assumes that there is <em>exactly</em> one outlier in the data (otherwise the test distribution is not well-defined). Speaking as a statistician, I'd say that this is a very strong prior belief on the distribution.